# Couldn't find 'kotlinPlugin' and 'darkThemeColors'

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

While I was trying to use jetpack's compose library, I was stuck at following the step mentioned in jetpack documentation (source: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#compose-compiler). I was unable to use kotlinPlugin as I got the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method kotlinPlugin() for arguments [androidx.compose:compose-compiler:0.1.0-dev02] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Also, I could not able to use **darkThemeColors** and **lightThemeColors**. Following are the Gradle dependencies I added.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    kotlinPlugin "androidx.compose:compose-compiler:0.1.0-dev02"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev02'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev02'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev02'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.50'
}
```

Am I missing any dependency? I checked **MaterialTheme** and **MaterialColors** classes, but didn't find darkThemeColors and lightThemeColors.

Answer (score 2):

In `jetpackCompose` sample app `jetnews` the `darkThemeColors` and `lightThemeColors` define in `Themes.kt` file exmaple below so you need define Colors.

```
val lightThemeColors = MaterialColors(
    primary = Color(0xFFDD0D3C),
    primaryVariant = Color(0xFFC20029),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    secondary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.Black,
    background = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color.Black,
    surface = Color.White,
    onSurface = Color.Black,
    error = Color(0xFFD00036),
    onError = Color.White
)

/**
 * Note: Dark Theme support is not yet available, it will come in 2020. This is just an example of
 * using dark colors.
 */
val darkThemeColors = MaterialColors(
    primary = Color(0xFFEA6D7E),
    primaryVariant = Color(0xFFDD0D3E),
    onPrimary = Color.Black,
    secondary = Color(0xFF121212),
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    surface = Color(0xFF121212),
    background = Color(0xFF121212),
    onBackground = Color.White,
    onSurface = Color.White
)
```

In below screenshot of `jetnews` project 
[image]
For `jetnews` sample check this link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#sample

Comment: Thank you. I thought android has defined some default themes. That is why I worried that I might miss some dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can define **darkThemeColors** and **lightThemeColors** as you prefer.

With `1.0.0-beta02` just use the [**`lightColors`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#lightcolors) and [**`darkColors`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#darkcolors) functions.
Something like:

```
val purple500 = Color(0xFF6200EE)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
        primary = purple500,
        primaryVariant = purple700,
        secondary = Color(0xFF03DAC6),
        onSecondary = Color.White
)
```

For example you can define:

```
@Composable
fun MaterialThemeSample(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {

    val lightColorsPalette = lightColors(
            primary = Color(0xFF1EB980),
            secondary = Color(0xFF03DAC6)
    )
    val darkColorsPalette = darkColors(
            primary = Color(0xFF66ffc7),
            secondary = Color.Red
    )

    val colors = if (darkTheme) darkColorsPalette else lightColorsPalette

    MaterialTheme(
            colors = colors,
            typography = typography,
            shapes = shapes,
            content = content
    )
}
```

and use it:

```
    setContent {
        MaterialThemeSample() {

            .....
        }
    }
```